# in Numpy, how to zip two 2-D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zip

For example I have 2 arrays

```
a = array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6, 7]])
b = array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

How can I `zip` `a` and `b` so I get

```
c = array([[(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)],
           [(4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7)]])
```

?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> np.dstack((a,b))
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [5, 5],
        [6, 6],
        [7, 7]]])
```

If you must have tuples:

```
>>> np.array(zip(a.ravel(),b.ravel()), dtype=('i4,i4')).reshape(a.shape)
array([[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)],
       [(4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

---

For Python 3+ you need to expand the `zip` iterator object. Please note that this is horribly inefficient:

```
>>> np.array(list(zip(a.ravel(),b.ravel())), dtype=('i4,i4')).reshape(a.shape)
array([[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)],
       [(4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: For the second command I get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'zip'` - why is that?

Comment: @Make42 In Python 3 `zip` returns an iterator. See edited answer.

Comment: (In Python 3) I don't need the `.ravel()` call.

Answer (score 9):

```
np.array([zip(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also specify the transpose indices:

```
c = np.array([a,b]).transpose(1,2,0)
```