# Python coding question regarding "stacking arrays to an array"

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, for-loop

I have a simple Python coding question regarding "stacking array inside array". Here, I have several arrays as follows:

```
a1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]) 
a2 = np.array([[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]])
a3 = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])
a4 = np.array([[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]])
a5 = np.array([[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]])
```

And, here is the output that I want:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5]]])
```

I want to stack a1 to a5 arrays into an array.

However, I don't have ideas for generating such output by using for-loop iterations. Could you provide some ideas for solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be looking for [`dstack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960441/in-numpy-how-to-zip-two-2-d-arrays).

Comment: @metatoaster, `dstack` would make a (3,3,5) array.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can directly list them and convert to array:

```
np.array([a1,a2, a3, a4, a5])

array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not surprisingly, to stack arrays you use the stack function:

```
np.stack([a1, a2, a3, a4, a5])
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 5]]])
```

Comment: In this case `stack` with its default axis does same thing as `np.array`.